# Activate HTML5 required validation with javascript and get result

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I've searched for a solution for hours but I can't find anything helpful in my case...

So, I have a form with an id, inputs within the form with required attribute. I also have a javascript function that send the form data to the PHP server through AJAX.

What I want is: when I click on my validation button, the JS function launches and check if the form is filled correctly (like it does with a normal submit). If it's not I'd like the required input message to show up, and my function to stop. If it is, I'd like my function to continue.

Here's a simplified version of my HTML code:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" id="myinput" required />
   <img src="img/some_img.png" onClick="do_js();" />
</form>
```

And the Javascript code:

```
function do_js()
{
   /* getting my form */
   var myform = document.getElementById('myform');

   /* HERE I want to check if my form is correctly filled */
   /* but not with a custom validation, I want the HTML5 required stuff to activate */
   /* then IF my form is okay, i want to send data through ajax */

   /* getting my data */
   var some_value = document.getElementById('myinput').value;

   /* sending my data */
   xhr.open('POST', 'ajax_page.php', true);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { /* result stuff */ };
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   xhr.send('myvalue='+some_value);
}
```

I'm working in PLAIN JAVASCRIPT (not with jQuery).

Comment: Isn't that exactly the default browser behavior? It doesn't send the form if the validation doesn't pass

Comment: Oke, I suggest you do simple validation in your browser (prevent submit), and the complex serverside validation should perform after submission (and result in feedback). Alternative is to submit form `onSuccess()` (callback should provide info whether or not it passed, but that can still be manipulated by JS gurus)

Comment: sorry, my bad.. In that case you should not add do_js but you should have this `onSubmit()`. `<form action='ajax_page.php' onSubmit='copyData();'>` right..? I think if you want form validation to kick in, you will have to submit the form and not do manual ajax call..?

Comment: you can use form.checkValidity() and input.validity.valid to tell ahead of time.

Comment: I think I'm gonna try with `checkValidity()` in my JS function. However, to display the "required" message, I do a `myform.submit();`, after I put a `onSubmit="return false;"` on my form. But my page is still refreshing... Can't understand why. In fact, what I REALLY want is to dynamically display the HTML5 "required" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event [`onSubmit`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp).

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form input[type=submit]{
  background:url(img/some_img.png) top right no-repeat;
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(){
  if(/*Your conditions to validate form*/){
    /* send your form with ajax here */
  }else{
    /* create your error message here */
  }

  return false; // for not reload your page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I really don't want the page to refresh. I guess in the `return true` case, the form will submit normally and the page will refresh. I want my page to stay, and my data to be sent with Ajax, but I also want the "required message" (in HTML5) to display if the inputs are not filled correctly. Sorry if my question is not clear enough :(

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA My fault, i updated my answer. If you hava question for how create message error or how validate correctly and send form, say it to me.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot man, that will do it! I was close but not enough. Really, thanks for your help. :)